# group by pandas removes duplicates

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe (df)

```
a     b     c
1     2     20
1     2     15
2     4     30
3     2     20
3     2     15
```

and I want to recognize only max values from column c

I tried

```
a = df.loc[df.groupby('b')['c'].idxmax()]
```

but it group by removes duplicates so I get

```
    a     b     c
    1     2     20
    2     4     30
```

it removes rows 3 because they are the same was rows 1.

Is it any way to write the code to not remove duplicates?

Comment: Maybe use `groupby(['a', 'b'])`?

Comment: It probably should not be called as being removed, but that's what means by 'grouping by'.

Comment: @Cleb, thanks that worked!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just also take column `a` into account when you do the `groupby`:

```
a = df.loc[df.groupby(['a', 'b'])['c'].idxmax()]

   a  b   c
0  1  2  20
2  2  4  30
3  3  2  20
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you need:

```
df = df[df['c'] == df.groupby('b')['c'].transform('max')] 
print (df)
   a  b   c
0  1  2  20
2  2  4  30
3  3  2  20
```

Difference in changed data:

```
print (df)
   a  b   c
0  1  2  30
1  1  2  30
2  1  2  15
3  2  4  30
4  3  2  20
5  3  2  15

#only 1 max rows per groups a and b
a = df.loc[df.groupby(['a', 'b'])['c'].idxmax()]
print (a)
   a  b   c
0  1  2  30
3  2  4  30
4  3  2  20

#all max rows per groups b
df1 = df[df['c'] == df.groupby('b')['c'].transform('max')] 
print (df1)
   a  b   c
0  1  2  30
1  1  2  30
3  2  4  30

#all max rows per groups a and b
df2 = df[df['c'] == df.groupby(['a', 'b'])['c'].transform('max')] 
print (df2)
   a  b   c
0  1  2  30
1  1  2  30
3  2  4  30
4  3  2  20
```

Comment: Why is this better or what does it do differently as what Cleb wrote?

Comment: @NoobProgrammer - Added a bit different data for difference.

Comment: I understand, but I need first one, so Im gonna check Cleb's answer. But this one will definitely come in handy some day.  Have a nice day, and thanks for effort.

Comment: @NoobProgrammer - No probem, for you too.